# Group results returned by elasticsearch query based on query terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am very new with elasticsearch. I am facing an issue building a query. My document structure is like:

```
{
  latlng: {
    lat: '<some-latitude>',
    lon: '<some-longitude>'
  },
  gmap_result: {<Some object>}
}
```

I am doing a search on a **list** of lat-long. For each coordinate, I am fetching a result that is within 100m. I have been able to do this part. But, the tricky part is that I do not know which results in the output correspond to the which query term. I think this requires using aggregations at some level, but I am currently clueless on how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate query is the correct approach.  You can learn about them here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

An example is below.  In this example, I am using a `match` query to find all instances of the word `test` in the field `title` and then aggregating the field `status` to count the number of results with the word `test` that are in each status.

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
       {
          "match": {
            "title": "*test*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count_by_status": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

The results look like this:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 346,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "count_by_status": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Open",
          "doc_count": 283
        },
        {
          "key": "Completed",
          "doc_count": 36
        },
        {
          "key": "On Hold",
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        {
          "key": "Withdrawn",
          "doc_count": 10
        },
        {
          "key": "Declined",
          "doc_count": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you provide your query, it would help us give a more specific aggregate query for you to use.